# What makes this answer "spam or rude or abusive"? Is it that one use of a swear word?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, rude-or-abusive

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383043/13552470) *(10K+ link)* was marked as spam or rude or abusive, screenshot for those with less than 10K rep:

[image]

I can totally see why it would be deleted as NAA *(not an answer)*, but spam or rude or abusive? If it's the swear word I can understand too, but I'm sure that's not the case, as there are plenty of other posts that swear but don't get deleted as so.

Comment: That was deleted 12 years ago...

Comment: As far as I know it only needs one flag as "rude" to marked as that. So I guess someone flagged it and a mod deemed this answer unhelpful anyway, so instead of editing the post, they removed it.

Comment: The answer is absolute trash.  Who cares? It was properly deleted. We deserve better than a useless vulgar answer like the one in the screenshot. If you want to provide examples of questions or answers with vulgarity masked or otherwise I will go ahead and flag those offensive contributions.

Comment: "vulgar answer"? having "fucking" in it hardly makes it vulgar...

Comment: @zoe it's still [not acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites)

Comment: There are so many posts that it's impossible to moderate every single one of them. That some posts with swear words still exist here should not be taken as evidence that swearing in posts in general is tolerated.

Comment: @RobertLongson That policy isn't enforced consistently

Comment: @zoe As I said above, no policy round here is enforced with absolute and perfect consistency. There's simply too much content compared to the number of people available and willing to moderate it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Except in the case of this particular policy, it's not down to a shortage of people willing to moderate; there's an active difference in how moderators handle it, and I've seen more who are lenient about it than who aren't.

Answer (score 12):

It was not deleted as spam/rude. Just because it is marked as such doesn't mean that it was deleted for that reason.

On the contrary, your screenshot clearly shows that it was deleted by a moderator, not by a red flag.

What probably happened is that some user raised a R/A flag due to obscenities in the post and the mod reviewed it, but decided it doesn't deserve red flag. It did deserve to be deleted though, so that mod simply deleted it but not as R/A